# How to set default sort column in extjs4 grid and change date format?

Tags: datetime, sorting, grid, extjs4

1-**How do I set the column to be sorted when the grid is created?**  then upon reloading the grid, it automatically utilize that sort to appropriately display the records.(without me clicing on it)
Can this be done on the grid itself so it is independent of the underlying data store?

2-**how do i change Date format displaying in a grid column?** 
my data render a date like this `/Date(1316020760837+0000)/`
i tried using `renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),// format: 'm d Y'`
but it gives me `NaN/NaN/NaN`

any help would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: Does your server return dates in the same format (`/Date(1316020760837+0000)/`)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

solved:

1. i used `sortOnLoad` with `sorters`

   ```
   var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   fields: ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'] 
   , data: []
   , sortOnLoad: true
   , sorters: { property: 'Item1', direction : 'DESC' }
   });
   ```
2. in my c# code i used `item.DateEnd.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")`. 
   see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for standard and custom format

or better
in extjs4 ,you should specify the *dateFormat* so Ext can parse it properly and you'll ensure it gets read ok.

```
   {name: 'Item1' , type : 'date',dateFormat :'MS'}
```

u can see [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date) for available format strings.